# Safe to install humidifier above furnace gas vent?

Tags: furnace, vent, exhaust-vent, humidifier

I'd like to add an [AprilAire 600 bypass humidifier.](https://www.aprilaire.com/whole-house-products/humidifier/model-600)

I plan to install the humidifier on the supply plenum, and the bypass duct on the return air.  The gas vent coming off the furnace is type B.

According to manufacturer, I need to keep combustibles 2 inches from [this vent](https://www.mtlfab.com/index.php?pid=224&aid=566&pg=type%20b%20gas%20vent%20pipe%20%26%20fittings)

So long as I maintain the 2-inch clearance, are there any safety issues with installing the humidifier above the gas vent?

[image: Furnace]

[image]